# Remove the last two directories in C#

Tags: c#

How to remove the last two directories ?

```
D:\11\PayrollSystem\PayrollSystem\bin\Debug\JCMPayrollSystem.accdb
```

Then the output should be:

```
D:\11\PayrollSystem\PayrollSystem\JCMPayrollSystem.accdb
```

need help

Comment: what is the context? do you mean during a build in visual studio? are you running a separate application? what have you tried?  Also, why do you want to move this file or files?

Comment: Can you please show the working code that you have tried. Quick way would be just to split the string on backslashes and then remove the 2,3 element from the end. As I said quick, might not work for a lot of cases though.

Comment: Use the `System.IO.Path` class. See marked duplicate for an example. `GetFileName()` will give you the file name. `GetDirectoryName()` will give you the path without the file name. Calling it iteratively will remove successive directories.

Comment: I used Path.GetFullPath(fileName), but the problem is I got output in the above question

Comment: newpath = oldpath.Replace(@"\bin\debug","");